# Selenium element click intercepted because of footer

Tags: java, selenium, viewport

I wrote this code:

```
try{
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(element);
    actions.perform();
    robot.delay(500);
    element.click();
}catch(WebDriverException clickIntercepted){
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
    element.click();
}
```

The element "element" is down outside the viewport, but when I move to the element, the page scrolls until the element is in the viewport, but it is behind the footer so when I try to click on it I get a click intercepted exception. To bypass this I press the page down key and release, the problem is that it works only if my browser is on top of the screen, and if I'm doing something else it doesn't work.
Is it possible to scroll until the element isn't covered by the footer without using javascriptexecutor or pressing the page down key?
I tried also

> moveToElement(element, x, y)

but it's the same as moveToElement(element)

This is the HTML code of the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="bottom">
                        <div id="errorboxcomponent" class="">
        <div id="decisionTB" style="display:none;">
    <div id="errorBoxDecision" class="errorBox TBfixedPosition">
        <div class="head"><h4 id="errorBoxDecisionHead">-</h4></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <span id="errorBoxDecisionContent">-</span>
            <div class="response">
                <div style="float:left; width:180px;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="yes"><span id="errorBoxDecisionYes">.</span></a>
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; width:180px;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="no"><span id="errorBoxDecisionNo">.</span></a>
                </div>
                <br class="clearfloat">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foot"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fadeBox" class="fadeBox fixedPostion" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        <span id="fadeBoxStyle" class="success"></span>
        <p id="fadeBoxContent"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="notifyTB" style="display:none;">
    <div id="errorBoxNotify" class="errorBox TBfixedPosition">
        <div class="head"><h4 id="errorBoxNotifyHead">-</h4></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <span id="errorBoxNotifyContent">-</span>
            <div class="response">
                <div>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ok">
                        <span id="errorBoxNotifyOk">.</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <br class="clearfloat">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foot"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      initBuffBar();

initIndex();

    </script>

<div id="siteFooter">
            <div class="content" style="font-size:10px">
                 <div class="fleft textLeft">
                     <a class="tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile overlay" href="URL;component=changelog&amp;ajax=1" data-overlay-class="popupWidthFixed" data-overlay-iframe="true" data-iframe-width="680" data-overlay-title="Note di versione" title="Note di versione">7.2.1</a>
                     <a class="homeLink" href="URL" target="_blank">...</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="fright textRight">
                     <a href="URL" target="_blank">Help</a>|
                     <a href="URL" target="_blank">Forum</a>|
                     <a class="overlay" href="URL;component=rules&amp;ajax=1" data-overlay-iframe="true" data-iframe-width="450" data-overlay-title="Regole">Rules</a>|
                     <a href="URL;product=..." target="_blank">Contatti</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is the element:

```
<img src="https://g1.ge.gsv.net/cdn9d/8e0e60340445budse18a1804b42f179.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="moon" class="icon-moon">
```

The footer is fixed at the bottom of the DOM so the element gets behind it.

Here you can see the "moon" element, like the ones marked, behind the footer after moveToElement(element)

[image: Immagine.png]

Comment: Please provide your DOM or url

Comment: @Rock it's a browser game and if you haven't an account you cannot see the element and the footer

Comment: Please provide required details as you have not mentioned on which element you are trying to perform  action. please go through link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , Also why you are using robot class for moving down you should handdle this through try block only

Comment: @Rock I've edited the question with the page source. I use the catch block because the other elements are inside the viewport so I have not to scroll to click them.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Your element Id")));

Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the element won't move from behind the footer until I scroll down manually the page. I get a timeout exeception. I'm trying to upload a screenshot of the problem

Comment: Javascript works, but it can be detected by the site

Comment: I hope its not because iframe present on the page , Also, you mean to say action class & javascript are not working with moveToElement add thats the reason you are using robot key press events.

Comment: I use it because if the browser is on top, it can scroll down pressing page down key on keyboard.
The footer is inside an iframe, the element when I use moveToElement stays behind the footer, so if I try to click the element, the click gets intercepted by the footer

Comment: you can also use js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");  for scrooling which will scroll down the page by 1000 pixel vertical. Also you can scroll to element using js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element); and then perform click on it. have you tried this?

Comment: yes, I tried and it works, but it is detectable by the site because i'm injecting javascript and the user gets banned.

Comment: What do you mean by detectable by site? If it's working then action class should also work without any issue

Comment: I mean that the site detects that it's not a person but a bot.
Action class works, the page actually scrolls down, but not enough because it stops when the element is behind the footer's iframe so it isn't clickable.

Comment: As per your code you are using robot class for scrolling down then clicking on the element and it's working without any issue then why you are not using same strategy with action class just scroll down using action class and then use web element click without action class.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element by using `JavascriptExecutor` click as the `JavascriptExecutor` click methods directly interacts with the dom structure.
You can do it like:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//img[@alt='moon' and @class='icon-moon']")));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```